# AWS Lambda to get specific tag value

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am looking to get specific tags from AWS in Lambda.

```
[{'Key': 'other', 'Value': 'other'}, {'Key': 'snstopic', 'Value': 'arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789:TestEmail'}, {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'test-user'}]
```

I want the value of the key `Name`.

This is how I am doing it now; but the issue is that the tag Name won't always be #2.

```
name = exported_json[2]['Value']
```

This is running in AWS Lambda.

Comment: Compact option: `name = {d["Key"]: d["Value"] for d in lst}.get("Name", None)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```py
exported_json = [{'Key': 'other', 'Value': 'other'}, {'Key': 'snstopic', 'Value': 'arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789:TestEmail'}, {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'test-user'}]

names = [dict['Value'] for dict in exported_json if dict['Key'] == 'Name']

if len(names) > 0:
  print(names[0])
```

The `if` at the end handles the situation where there is no `Name` tag, but if there are multiple `Name` tags is just returns the first one.